# how to relate data of a large 3 dimensional galaxy to test whether homogeneity is supported by the data and to determine what the homogeneity scale?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy

Suppose that you have a database of three-dimensional galaxy coordinates x; y; z
that covered a large volume of, say, 3 Gpc  3 Gpc  3 Gpc. Using your skill and
judgement, suggest how you might use the data to test whether homogeneity is
supported by the data and to determine what the homogeneity scale might be
(e.g. 50; 100; : : : 500Mpc). Note: there is no right answer to this; attempt to
devise a method of using the data that might plausibly work. What might be the
shortcomings of your method?

I know some data but i cannot relate it to answer the question, i cannot figure out how tackle such questions as a beginner to the cosmology studies.

i know that the cosmological principle can be related on large scales of 100 MPC or more. a sphere of a 3 dimensional galaxy with a large volume as this of 3 GPc has a roughly the same pattern of superclusters and voids, and the universe on scales of 100MPC or more appears to be isotropic, so it implies homogeneity.

just i need to know if this is a good point or not and how to determine the homogeneity scale?

is it related to the density of the galaxy or what?

thank you in advance.

Comment: They are asking how you will analyze the data for homogeneity. How would you test for a random distribution?  Since you also know that cosmological expansion comes to play at 100 Mpc you want to think about whether you need to account for the fact that the data has galaxies that emitted their light at different times, up to 3 billion years ago, you are are seeing galaxies from different times. And remember that homogeneity means a statistically uniform distribution in space, not time.